# How can I efficiently half forward/backward fill a gap in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with datetimes as index. There are some gaps in the index so I upsample it to have 1 second gap only. I want to fill the gaps by doing half forward filling (from the left side of the gap) and half backward filling (from the right side of the gap).

Input:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3
2000-01-01 00:04:10    4
```

Upsampled Input, with 10 second:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:10    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:20    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:30    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:40    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:50    NaN
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:10    NaN
2000-01-01 00:01:20    NaN
2000-01-01 00:01:30    NaN
2000-01-01 00:01:40    NaN
2000-01-01 00:01:50    NaN
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:10    NaN
2000-01-01 00:02:20    NaN
2000-01-01 00:02:30    NaN
2000-01-01 00:02:40    NaN
2000-01-01 00:02:50    NaN
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3.0
2000-01-01 00:04:10    4.0
```

Output I want:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:10    0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:20    0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:30    0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:40    1.0
2000-01-01 00:00:50    1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:10    1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:20    1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:30    1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:40    2.0
2000-01-01 00:01:50    2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:10    2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:20    2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:30    2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:40    3.0
2000-01-01 00:02:50    3.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3.0
2000-01-01 00:04:10    4.0
```

I managed to get the results I want by getting the edges of the gaps after the upsampling, performing a forward fill across all the gap, and then updating just the right half with the value of the right edge, but since my data is so large, it takes forever to run as some of my files have 1M gaps to fill. I basically do this using a for loop that goes through all the identified gaps.

Is there a way this could be done faster?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I only want to upsample and fill gaps where the time difference is smaller than or equal to a given value, in the example only those up to 1 minute, so the last 2 rows won't have an upsample and filling between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

```
ts = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3], pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=4, freq='min'))
```

---

#### `merge_asof` with `direction='nearest'`

```
pd.merge_asof(
    ts.asfreq('10s').to_frame('left'),
    ts.to_frame('right'),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    direction='nearest'
)

                     left  right
2000-01-01 00:00:00   0.0      0
2000-01-01 00:00:10   NaN      0
2000-01-01 00:00:20   NaN      0
2000-01-01 00:00:30   NaN      0
2000-01-01 00:00:40   NaN      1
2000-01-01 00:00:50   NaN      1
2000-01-01 00:01:00   1.0      1
2000-01-01 00:01:10   NaN      1
2000-01-01 00:01:20   NaN      1
2000-01-01 00:01:30   NaN      1
2000-01-01 00:01:40   NaN      2
2000-01-01 00:01:50   NaN      2
2000-01-01 00:02:00   2.0      2
2000-01-01 00:02:10   NaN      2
2000-01-01 00:02:20   NaN      2
2000-01-01 00:02:30   NaN      2
2000-01-01 00:02:40   NaN      3
2000-01-01 00:02:50   NaN      3
2000-01-01 00:03:00   3.0      3
```

---

#### `reindex` with `method='nearest'`

```
ts.reindex(ts.asfreq('10s').index, method='nearest')

2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
2000-01-01 00:00:10    0
2000-01-01 00:00:20    0
2000-01-01 00:00:30    1
2000-01-01 00:00:40    1
2000-01-01 00:00:50    1
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:01:10    1
2000-01-01 00:01:20    1
2000-01-01 00:01:30    2
2000-01-01 00:01:40    2
2000-01-01 00:01:50    2
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
2000-01-01 00:02:10    2
2000-01-01 00:02:20    2
2000-01-01 00:02:30    3
2000-01-01 00:02:40    3
2000-01-01 00:02:50    3
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3
Freq: 10S, dtype: int64
```

---

**Note:** that the decision on how to determine nearest produces slightly different results between the two solutions.

```
pd.merge_asof(
    ts.asfreq('10s').to_frame('left'),
    ts.to_frame('merge_asof'),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    direction='nearest'
).assign(reindex=ts.reindex(ts.asfreq('10s').index, method='nearest'))

                     left  merge_asof  reindex
2000-01-01 00:00:00   0.0           0        0
2000-01-01 00:00:10   NaN           0        0
2000-01-01 00:00:20   NaN           0        0
2000-01-01 00:00:30   NaN           0        1  # This row is different
2000-01-01 00:00:40   NaN           1        1
2000-01-01 00:00:50   NaN           1        1
2000-01-01 00:01:00   1.0           1        1
2000-01-01 00:01:10   NaN           1        1
2000-01-01 00:01:20   NaN           1        1
2000-01-01 00:01:30   NaN           1        2  # This row is different
2000-01-01 00:01:40   NaN           2        2
2000-01-01 00:01:50   NaN           2        2
2000-01-01 00:02:00   2.0           2        2
2000-01-01 00:02:10   NaN           2        2
2000-01-01 00:02:20   NaN           2        2
2000-01-01 00:02:30   NaN           2        3  # This row is different
2000-01-01 00:02:40   NaN           3        3 
2000-01-01 00:02:50   NaN           3        3
2000-01-01 00:03:00   3.0           3        3
```

Comment: This could work for me! I forgot to add this in the question: what if I want to ignore some gaps and just fills those that meet a condition (like gaps in time smaller than 1 minute)?

Comment: Read the documentation for either. There is a tolerance argument

Comment: I did, and tried adding `tolerance=pd.Timedelta('00:01:00')` to only reindex rows with up to 1 minute of gap, but is not working.

Answer (score 3):

If you data is 1 min apart, you can do:

```
df.set_index(0).asfreq('10S').ffill(limit=3).bfill(limit=2)
```

output:

```
                       1
0                       
2000-01-01 00:00:00  0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:10  0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:20  0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:30  0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:40  1.0
2000-01-01 00:00:50  1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:00  1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:10  1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:20  1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:30  1.0
2000-01-01 00:01:40  2.0
2000-01-01 00:01:50  2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:00  2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:10  2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:20  2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:30  2.0
2000-01-01 00:02:40  3.0
2000-01-01 00:02:50  3.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00  3.0
```

Comment: The gaps have between 2 and 60 seconds, the upsampling I do is of 1 second, could it still work if I know which value set `limit` to?

Comment: `limit` option tells how far you would fill. In your case, forward fill 3 values and backward fill 2 values.